# Small CSS bug with <pre><hr> ... <hr> ... <hr></pre>

Tags: bug, design, code-formatting

The following formatting strategy

```
<pre>
Line 1
<hr>
Line 2
<hr>
Line 3
</pre>
```

renders like this for me (in Chrome) as of March 2021 (image edited to be narrower so it doesn't blur):

[image]

and currently looks like this (above is the image, below is the HTML):

```
Line 1

Line 2

Line 3
```

This is because `<pre>` tags live inside a `div.s-prose`, and `.s-prose hr`s currently have `margin-bottom: var(--s-prose-spacing)` — with the exception of...

#### **Inhales**

`.s-prose p:last-child, .s-prose dl:last-child, .s-prose blockquote:last-child, .s-prose table:last-child, .s-prose .s-table-container:last-child, .s-prose .s-link-preview:last-child, .s-prose hr:last-child, .s-prose ol:last-child, .s-prose ul:last-child, .s-prose img:last-child, .s-prose pre:last-child, .s-prose h1:last-child, .s-prose h2:last-child, .s-prose h3:last-child, .s-prose h4:last-child, .s-prose h5:last-child, .s-prose h6:last-child, .s-prose p:only-child, .s-prose dl:only-child, .s-prose blockquote:only-child, .s-prose table:only-child, .s-prose .s-table-container:only-child, .s-prose .s-link-preview:only-child, .s-prose hr:only-child, .s-prose ol:only-child, .s-prose ul:only-child, .s-prose img:only-child, .s-prose pre:only-child, .s-prose h1:only-child, .s-prose h2:only-child, .s-prose h3:only-child, .s-prose h4:only-child, .s-prose h5:only-child, .s-prose h6:only-child`

The above mega-selector does just one thing: `margin-bottom: 0`.

Hopefully this selector is just a "reset all the things" type of thing :) <sup><sub>yikes</sub></sup>

Comment: I need some pasta sauce for that spaghetti css.

Comment: That selector is twice as long as it needs to be. Every :only-child is necessarily also a :last-child. Both are equally specific, so the inclusion of :only-child there serves no function whatsoever regardless of where in the stylesheet that CSS rule is.